# Wordpress Barracuda Loadbalancer SSL offload

Tags: ssl, wordpress

If I have Barracuda off load SSL for a Wordpress site, does Wordpress need to be set up as https or http?

Comment: That depends a bit on the sensitivity of the data and how much you trust the network between the Barracuda and the WordPress install. The answer will be potentially different for a WP install handling PCI data versus a public blog.

Comment: I was looking at just the machanics of it. I know I needif ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'){
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
}

Answer (score 1):

Offloading SSL means the load balancer is doing the ssl parts ahead of Wordpress. In this case, the SSL Cert is normally installed on the Barracuda box. The connections are then sent to the back end server(s) using HTTP. If you want HTTPS on Wordpress, that's doable too by putting the connection in TCP mode rather than HTTP mode. The load balancer would normally set the X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Protocol HTTP headers so Wordpress would recognize that the connection was requested in SSL.